# Is it possible to explode a column without including the values from other columns?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

In my scenario, I'm exploding an array column so that I have one record per row so that I can perform a join, and then I recombine those exploded columns together

```
+--------------+-------+------------------------+
|     body     |  ID   |     array_column       |
+--------------+-------+------------------------+
| (large data) | guid1 |     (entry1,entry2)    |
+--------------+-------+------------------------+
| (large data) | guid2 | (entry3,entry4,entry5) |
+--------------+-------+------------------------+
```

->

```
+--------------+-------+-----------------+
|     body     |  ID   |  array_column   |
+--------------+-------+-----------------+
| (large data) | guid1 |      entry1     |
+--------------+-------+-----------------+
|     null     | guid1 |      entry2     |
+--------------+-------+-----------------+
| (large data) | guid2 |      entry3     |
+--------------+-------+-----------------+
|     null     | guid2 |      entry4     |
+--------------+-------+-----------------+
|     null     | guid2 |      entry5     |
+--------------+-------+-----------------+
```

->

```
+--------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------+
|     body     |  ID   |                   array_column                    |
+--------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------+
| (large data) | guid1 |            (entry1_enriched,entry2_enriched)      |
+--------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------+
| (large data) | guid2 | (entry3_enriched,entry4_enriched,entry5_enriched) |
+--------------+-------+---------------------------------------------------+
```

Notice how after the explode, the body only exists in one of the explodes, and otherwise it's filled with null values. This is what I would like to occur. Right now it's being filled with the large body in each row, which is causing memory issues for us. I've considered splitting the table, dropping columns, and rejoining it with itself later, but because I'm operating on streaming data, this isn't really an option.

P.S. I'm not concerned with the re-joining (this part is working), only if there is an easy way to fill certain exploded rows' columns with dummy values to minimize space consumption

Answer (score 1):

**It is possible to explode without including the values of other columns, but there is no built-in function to do so, you have to do it by hand**

To do so, you transform your `array_column` from an array of string to an array of `struct<String, String>`, the first field of struct contains your `body` column for the first entry in the array and `None` for others entries and the last field contains an entry of your `array_column` array. This new array is built using an [user-defined function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.udf.html). Then you drop column `body` and perform your `explode`:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, ArrayType, StructType, StructField

class Element:

    def __init__(self, body, entry):
        self.body = body
        self.entry = entry


@F.udf(returnType=ArrayType(StructType([StructField("body", StringType()), StructField("entry", StringType())])))
def array_with_body(body, array_column):
    result = []
    for i in range(0, len(array_column)):
        if i == 0:
            result.append(Element(body, array_column[i]))
        else:
            result.append(Element(None, array_column[i]))
    return result


before_join_df = input_df.withColumn(
    "array_column", 
    array_with_body(F.col('body'), F.col('array_column'))
  ) \
  .drop('body') \
  .withColumn('array_column', F.explode('array_column')) \
  .select(
    F.col('id'), 
    F.col('array_column.body').alias('body'),
    F.col('array_column.entry').alias('array_column')
  )
```

You then get your expected `before_join_df` dataframe:

```
+-----+------------+------------+
|id   |body        |array_column|
+-----+------------+------------+
|guid1|(large data)|entry1      |
|guid1|null        |entry2      |
|guid2|(large data)|entry3      |
|guid2|null        |entry4      |
|guid2|null        |entry5      |
+-----+------------+------------+
```

You then perform your join and transformation, and to retrieve your `final_df` dataframe from `after_join_df` dataframe you can perform following transformations:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

final_df = after_join_df.groupBy('id') \
  .agg(
    F.max(F.col('body')).alias('body'), 
    F.collect_list(F.col('array_column')).alias('array_column')
  )
```

And `final_df` is as follow:

```
+-----+------------+---------------------------------------------------+
|id   |body        |array_column                                       |
+-----+------------+---------------------------------------------------+
|guid1|(large data)|[entry1_enriched, entry2_enriched]                 |
|guid2|(large data)|[entry3_enriched, entry4_enriched, entry5_enriched]|
+-----+------------+---------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Great idea! Since I have several large columns actually, and since serialization is expensive, I have an optimization for this. Instead of <string, string>, the object should be <customClass, string> where custom class is a case class defining all of the columns I want to nullify and retain. Furthermore if I wanted to avoid using a UDF as well I could define it as <col1Class, col2Class, col3Class, ..., string>

Answer (score 0):

[RDD.flatMap](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.flatMap.html) can be used. A function (called `flatten` in the code below) takes a single row from the input data and returns an iterator over a list of result rows. In this list the first row contains the `large data` while for all other rows this column is set to `None`:

```python
df= ...

def flatten(row):
    body=row[0]
    id=row[1]
    entries=row[2]
    return iter([(body, id, entries[0])] + [(None, id, e) for e in entries[1:]])

flattend_rdd=df.rdd.flatMap(flatten)

spark.createDataFrame(flattend_rdd, df.columns).show()
```

Output:

```
+--------------+-----+------------+
|          body|   ID|array_column|
+--------------+-----+------------+
|(large data 1)|guid1|      entry1|
|          null|guid1|      entry2|
|(large data 2)|guid2|      entry3|
|          null|guid2|      entry4|
|          null|guid2|      entry5|
+--------------+-----+------------+
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for in my other question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69307969/inverse-of-groupbykey-mapgroups-in-spark?noredirect=1#comment122505361_69307969

Comment: And it seems like the most simple and proper solution for what I'm looking for